# OnTouchListener - MotionEvent.ACTION_UP working incorrectly after turning screen off

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, ontouchlistener

The problem occurs on Android version 4.4.2.

I implemented a functionality that fires an event after pressing a button for 5 seconds. I've set OnTouchListener on the button and I track the events MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP. It works fine until I turn off the screen and turn it on again. Here is the "black magic" part:

While pressing the button, the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is fired automatically after a constant period of time, around 1.2 seconds. At first I thought it might have something to do with [ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getLongPressTimeout()) but it returns 500 ms, so this doesn't seem to be the case. Reinstalling the app, rotating the screen, restarting the device, nothing helps. The only way I can make it work normally again is by force stopping it in the application list or swiping it off from recent application list.

Here is a small sample code you can use for reproducing the error:

```
btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ACTION_UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be a bug on MTK Rom that we're using. The problem doesn't occur on emulator and Samsung s4 mini with same version of Android.